# switch between three listfragments -android-

Tags: android, fragment, android-listfragment

i trying to learn switching between listfragments
i have here three list fragments and i want to move between them using three buttons 
[image: this is main layout]

[image: implement of one of the listfragments]

[image: class of one of the fragments]

[image: main activity class]

and i have this error **                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mohamed.multilistfragment/com.example.mohamed.multilistfragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change every *listview ID* from 
`android:id="@+id/list"` to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```